# Two columns of equal height to reverse at breakpoint

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make two columns of equal height that reverse their stacking at an 845px breakpoint. How should I code my css for regular view vs the 845px @media?

[image]

What are the benefits and or shortcomings of either method?

Comment: Need to see your current code in order to determine that. If the 2 `divs` are `display: inline-block` then just simply changing it to `display: block` could handle that

Comment: Did you *try* anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.parent > .child-1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.parent > .child-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 845px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .parent > .child-1 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with `flex` and the `order` property. The basic idea is to stack the items, using their default DOM order (col 1 before col 2), then in a media query use the `order` property to swap the order so col 2 is to the left of col 1. Like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.col--1 {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.col--2 {
  border-color: blue;
  color: blue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 845px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .col--1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .col--2 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col col--1">
    COL 1<br/> DIV
  </div>
  <div class="col col--2">
    COL 2<br/> DIV
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! Exactly what I needed!